YAML template to prevent the use of certain variable group
I've created a YAML template to extends from with a fixed stage "Deploy" (can not be modified by users, only pass params) and an optional stage "PreDeploy" that should be entirely provided by template users (if they want to add this stage).
parameters:
- name: application
  type: string
  default: ""
- name: PreDeployStage
  type: stage
  default: 
     stage: 
     jobs:
     - job: 

stages:
- ${{ parameters.PreDeployStage }}
- stage: 'Deploy'

The pipeline which extends from this template could be something like this:
# azure-pipelines.yml
resources:
repositories:
- repository: temp
type: git
name: templates
ref: refs/heads/main

extends:
template: template.yml@temp
parameters:
Application: APP
PreDeployStage:
  stage: Custom
  jobs:
  - job: StoleSecrets
    variables:
      - group: Secrets
    pool: default
    steps:
      - task: Whatever task which access to the vars stored in Secrets 

There is a variable group called "Secrets" that should never be used in a stage other than "Deploy". In order to prevent template users to provide a stage which uses this variable group (either at stage level or job level) I was wondering if something like this can be used (idea would be to delete all references to "Secrets" variable group in the provided stage).
Is this possible?
EDIT
The workaround proposed by @Alvin Zhao - MSFT gives me a validation error on the steps section:

When trying to save, this is the result:

Seems that the problem is totally focused there because if I replaced the expression with a concrete task, passes validation and works as expected:

The script that currently consumes the template is:


Hi there, so may I assume your expectation is to prevent the variable group secrets from being used, unless the Deploy stage is consuming it?

Or say how to  prevent the variable group secrets from being used by other stages than Deploy stage?

Hi @Alvin Zhao - MSFT, the Deploy stage will always require "secrets" variable group, the idea is to not allow access to it from other stages

And if any other stage or job in that stage is trying to use secrets variable group during a build, the request should be rejected?

Both: rejection or just remove references to variable group are valid options (idea is to prevent the secrets from being accessed from the stage provided by user)

Sorry for the following-ups for confirmation, but a variable group can be referenced by adding to the variables section in your YAML definition file. Do you also need to restrict users from contributing to your repo?  You can use the security settings of the variable group for approvals and checks, which is designed for usage approval purpose. But removing the reference is another story; a user who can push commit to this YAML file in your repo can therefore change the variable group reference. May I know your current policy for that? Or would you like to narrow the expectation?

In fact I am using the required template check to allow access to "Secrets" variable group only when extending from this template. The problem is that the stage passed as parameter by users can also access to this variable group (makes sense: they are using the template :) ) so I am trying to remove references when running the pipeline (because, obviously, they can change whatever they want in the yaml file which extends the template). The template it is safe in a different Project with readonly permissions.

Then, may I ask if it is possible to store this required template in the repo from another project in the same organization, as you mentioned it would be safe when users only had read permissions right?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Hi @Josto, Having explored further on the actual requirement, I tested with several builds accordingly. Hope the modified YAML templates can resolve your query in this post. Thank you again for your amicable sharing, which I believe will benefit other community members with similar concerns. Cheers!

Based on the further disucssions, the pipeline had been passing a whole stage syntax as the value of ${{ parameters.PreDeployStage }} into the extended template.yml. Users were able modify the parameter value to be passed in the YAML defintion azure-pipelines.yml; if with variables: - group: Secrets added, the pipeline would proceed to reference the variable group Secrets.
The requirement is to first detect if the parameter value to be passed into template contains such lines to reference variable group Secrets and then remove to prevent them from passing.
Here are modifed YAML defintion (removing any possibly referenced variables group defined on stage level) and the template for your reference.
azure-pipelines.yml
# azure-pipelines.yml

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: temp
    type: git
    name: templates
    ref: refs/heads/main

extends:
  template: template.yml@temp
  parameters:
    Application: APP
    PreDeployStage:
      stage: Custom
      variables:
      - group: Secrets # Includes a variable Var1 with the value 1
      - group: VG-Y # Includes a variable VarY with the value Y
      jobs:
      - job: DoNothing
        variables:
        - group: Secrets 
        - group: VG-X # Includes a variable VarX with the value X
        pool: default
        steps:
        - script: |
            echo Whatever task which access to the vars stored in Secrets variable group
            echo "Stage variables defined in parameter $(jsonStageVar)"
            echo "Job variables defined in parameters $(jsonJobVar)"
            echo "Parameter expects to use Secrets varialbe group? - $(useSecrects)"

            echo The value of var1 in group Secrets is "$(Var1)"
            echo The value of varX in group VG-X is "$(VarX)"
            echo The value of varY in group VG-Y is "$(VarY)"


template.yml
# template.yml

parameters:
- name: application
  type: string
  default: ""
- name: PreDeployStage
  type: stage
  default: {}

stages:
- stage: ${{ parameters.PreDeployStage.stage }}
  variables:
  - name: jsonStageVar
    value: ${{ convertToJson(parameters.PreDeployStage.variables) }}
  - ${{ each stageVariable in parameters.PreDeployStage.variables }}:
    - ${{ if eq(stageVariable.group, 'Secrets') }}:
      - name: useSecrects
        value: true
    - ${{ else }}:
      - ${{ stageVariable }}
  jobs:
  - ${{ each tempJob in parameters.PreDeployStage.jobs}}:
    - job: ${{ tempJob.job }}
      pool: ${{ tempJob.pool }} 
      variables:
      - name: jsonJobVar
        value: ${{ convertToJson(tempJob.variables) }}
      - ${{ each jobVariable in tempJob.variables }}:
        - ${{ if eq(jobVariable.group, 'Secrets') }}:
          - name: useSecrects
            value: true
        - ${{ else }}:
          - ${{ jobVariable }}
      steps:
      - ${{ tempJob.steps }}


- stage: 'Deploy'
  jobs:
  - job: JobDeploy
    steps:
    - script: echo This is Deploy stage

From the expaned YAML defintion in the downloaded logs, we can see the  lines - group: secrets defined in the variables sections on stage and job levels are replaced.


Please also note that the modified template.yml splits some but not all properties of the stage and job(s) to be passed in. If other stage/job properties shall be passed, you need to add those mapping properties in temlate.yml as well; otherwise, they will be ignored during template expansion and will not take effect.

Hi @Alvin Zhao - MSFT thank you so much. Looks amazing but in my case do not pass the validation (I got a " Unexpected value '' " error just before of "- ${{ tempJob.steps }}" I am not able to figure out what is happening

Hi @Josto, Based on your update, I think the previous properties of the stage parameter was expanded correctly, right? Only the steps section might contain some syntax errors.

For this, first of all, please be careful about the indentations in each line under steps and I would also suggest you comment out each step then Validate the YAML syntax; thus task by task to locate the issue step(s).

In case the validation for steps part still fails, I am more than willing to help you with the syntax checking, but it might require you to share your actual YAML parameter contents with screenshots of the definition rather than a sample task in the original post. Please don't forget to scrub any sensitive or private information like tokens, password or certificates etc, since the community is publicly visible.

Hi @Alvin Zhao - MSFT, I added some context about the error on the question. Still struggling with it.

Hi @Josto, let me check this for a sec.

Hi @josto, what does your current azure-pipelines.yml look like? I mean especiallythe context under steps. Can you please try and replace those steps in azure-pipelines.yml with one or two lines - powershell: echo This is a test for a test? Keep steps: - ${{ tempJob.steps }}  in template.yml

I suspect the syntax error was caused by the steps section of the parameter value in  azure-pipelines.yml, which was to be inserted in 53rd line of template.yml.

if the parameter value to be passed into template was wrong, it would incur the same error during validation.

I included the azure-pipelines.yml for more context

Hi @Josto, the Validation passed in my YAML pipeline... So wired..

If possible, would you try creating a new pipeline with the YAML contents in my answer to see if the issue persists?

Don't know the reason but in my case the workaround proposed by @Alvin Zhao - MSFT only works changing this in the final "steps" section:
steps:
- ${{ each step in tempJob.steps}}:
  - ${{ step }}

